# Pressing [x] hides my apps

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, tasks

I reseted my windows after a blue screen of death and now I have the following issue:

When I press close in any app (like steam, discord) instead of closing them, it  minimizes them and just hides them. They stay minimized but **there are no icons of them in the minimized taskbar**.

So I can't close them unless I go into the tasks and press "End Task".

What can I do to fix it?

Running windows 10. Ask me if you need more details.

Thanks

Comment: Check the settings for each application. This is dependant on the application and not Windows. Look for a "minimise instead of close" type option.

Comment: It could be that they are not minimized but that the application hangs in the termination sequence. Did you try a Windows repair installation?

Comment: @eckes: He reinstalled Windows.

Comment: @Mokubai I am familiar with this. This is not the case though. It's some kind of bug or windows behavior.